# Selenium: get ID of a div with a class that has a space

Tags: python, selenium

I have a div that has a class of 'message clearfix default' with a subclass of 'data-message-id=XX'. My goal is to get that id 96375050. ive tried the .find_element_by_class_name however the class is 'message clearfix default' and it fails due to the spaces. Also since this is not a displayed piece there is not CSS to attach too.

[image]

How can I get 96375050 back?

```
<div class="message clearfix default" data-message-id="96375050" data-user-id="186772" data-user-login="MAS1271" id="message_96375050" data-ape="messages_96375050">
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find_element_by_xpath` to get the element:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="messageli"]//div[@class="message clearfix default"]')
msg_id = elem.get_attribute('data-message-id')
```

`[@class="text"]` uses exact matching , you can combine `and`&`contains` like:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="messageli"]//div[contains(@class,"message") and contains(@class,"default")]')
```

Comment: Hey thanks much! this saves me from pulling the whole html statement back and re it :).

Answer (score 2):

I know you already accepted an answer but it's much better to use a CSS selector in this case. If you choose XPath, you are doing a full string match to find that class so if the class order is changed or another class is added, your selector will no longer work. If you use a CSS selector, the order doesn't matter

```
msg_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.message.clearfix.default").get_attribute('data-message-id')
```

There's also better support for CSS selectors and they are faster than XPath.

Comment: Thanks jeff, both options would work great in the future for me and someone else. thanks for your input.